# Persistent connection not working at all

Tags: html, http, tcp, scapy, keep-alive

I am making a webserver with scapy, which is going pretty well. However, it's a pain in the butt for scapy to maintain different connections at the same time. So I want the client to make a persistent connection with the webserver that servers a html page with an image.

I have the client succesfully iniating a tcp handshake and obtaining the html page, **however**, it opens a new connection to download the image. Which I do **not** want.

I understand that in `HTTP/1.1` it is not necessary to send the `keep-alive` header, as it's a default. How come *Chrome* and *Firefox* still open more connections to download seperate files?

I am not sending a `Connection: close` header whatsoever, so I think it's weird that they do not maintain the same connection for all files on the webpage.

**EDIT**: Tried to use the actual `Keep-Alive: timeout=n, max = n` header. Still no result.

---

What could be the problem? Feel free to ask for details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistent connections do not forbid to use parallel connections, they only allow to re-use the same connection for more requests. But, with persistent connections you can only do multiple requests within the same connection one after the other. This means to get lots of resources it is usually faster to open multiple connections in parallel and use each of these connections to get multiple resources, e.g. using 4 connections in parallel to get 12 images (3 images with each connection) is faster then getting all the 12 images one after the other using a single connection.

Comment: Thank you, however, how can I forbid parallel connections?

Comment: I don't know if this can be configured at all.

Comment: You're right. I did some research. However I did find a solution: pipelining. So i'm now converting the webserver to only use a single pipeline connection (just for GET requests do)

Comment: Pipelining is only that the client can send multiple requests at once inside the same connection, but the replies will still be serialized in order of sending. This means the advantages of multiple connections still apply. And not all servers support pipelining. Are you sure the browser will only use a single connection in this case?

Comment: Did not think about that, I will have to figure out a way to forbid parallel connections.